# Getting "use of undeclared type 'NoError'" with ReactiveCocoa

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-cocoa

I am trying to learn ReactiveCocoa and have a hard time getting started. I keep hitting minor bumps as API and tutorials seems to be outdated quickly. Maybe I have the wrong impression.

Just trying to follow [this](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2015/04/28/reactive-cocoa-3-continued.html) I do not seem to have `NoError`.

[image]

It should be imported correctly, since I have access to `Signal`, `rac_textSignal` etc. but I don't know why NoError is not available.

Their [documentation](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/Documentation/DesignGuidelines.md#failures-behave-like-exceptions-and-propagate-immediately) mentions `NoError` as well but that leads to a [404](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/ReactiveCocoa/Swift/Errors.swift).

This [transition to RAC4](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/10/26/reactivecocoa-4-differences/) mentions `NoError` as well. Why is `NoError` undeclared? I am using ReactiveCocoa 4.0.1.

Edit: I just added `public enum NoError : ErrorType {}` to the top of the file and it works now. I am not sure if this is a proper solution to the problem though. It is not mentioned in guides and tutorials that I should extend `ErrorType` myself.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The reactive cocoa native `NoError` was removed in 4.0.1 in favour of [antitypicals](https://github.com/antitypical/Result) implementation in `Result` (adds `NoError` to `Result`, see [this](https://github.com/antitypical/Result/pull/132)). See e.g. issue #2704

- https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/issues/2704

We can see this explicitly used in the source files, e.g.

- `import enum Result.NoError` in [Property.swift](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/ReactiveCocoa/Swift/Property.swift).

Hence, you probably need to include (antitypicals) `Result` whenever you intend to use `NoError`. One suggested fix in the issue thread is

```
public typealias NoError = Result.NoError
```

Comment: Thanks, people seem to complain about breaking changes, I would not have figured this out. `import enum Result.NoError` and then `typealias` the error works for me.

Comment: @Filuren Happy to help. Since that works fine for you, your probably wont need it, but I'd keep an eye out on that open issue just in case.

Comment: That's true, this was technically a breaking change that we did not foresee.

Answer (score 4):

If you are seeing this now with **ReactiveSwift 6.0**, they removed the dependency on **Result**, which removes `NoError`.

Per their [release notes here](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveSwift/releases), the solution is to now use `Never`.

> - If you have used Result only as dependency of ReactiveSwift, remove
>     all instances of import Result, import enum Result.NoError or import
>     struct Result.AnyError and remove the Result Framework from your
>     project.
> - Replace all cases where NoError was used in a Signal or
>     SignalProducer with Never

The following example code shows how this should look now:

```
import ReactiveSwift

func example() -> SignalProducer<Void, Never> {
    return SignalProducer(value: ())
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you add "import Results" to the top of the page above your class,  NoError will no longer be an undeclared type!